# python3.7 не видет установленную библеотеку для PostGre через pip

Tags: python

Установил psycopg2 через pip 10.0.1, как истинный питонец. Все проиходит на Windows 10

Пытаюсь через import вызвать её и , но получаю ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'psycopg2'",)

Аналогично происходит psycopg2.extras. Тоже самое с py-postgresql...
Как это починить ?
Абсолютно такая же проблема в PythonShell, отчего проблема с средой разработки опускается. 
Что забавно pip прекрасно видит эти модули, стирает и устанавливает их по моей просьбе. До этого кое как, не без вашей помощи запустил Flask, скачивая его вроде как через pip - и оно до сих пор хорошо робит

Comment: версия python какая?

Comment: python3.7 само собой)

Comment: Только что отвалился flask - он и его перестал видеть . Накаркал

Comment: У вас, случаем, не несколько версий python?

Comment: Оу,- несколько. Это может все сломать?

Comment: Yes, of course!)

Comment: Тока что увидел что пакеты можно устанавливать в Vs для конкретной версии питона....  Сразу же поставил psycopg2 и все заработало. Спасибо за наводки. При том и pip версия сразу выскочила другая и установка снова пошла, а не писалось, что мол пакет уже установлен ....

Comment: А за что минусы то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас несколько версий python, то pip устанавливает пакеты на ту версию python, которая в системе по умолчанию. То есть устанавливаете вы пакет через pip, на одну, а импортируете в другой.

Чтобы избежать подобных проблем, придется указывать нужный python явно

Пишите полный путь до python.exe(нужной версии) потом -m pip install psycopg2. Должно получиться что-то типа

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -m pip install psycopg2
```